# Making TAB Press go to the next field

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to know how I can skip to the next field by pressing tab. Currently I have three lineEdits A , B and C. When I am on A pressing TAB takes me to LineEdit C. Any suggestions on how I could uniform it and move to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tab order is messed up. If you use Qt designer, there's a mode where it shows you the tab order. Just click the controls in the right order.

If you manually create the windows in code, I believe the order of creation becomes the default tab order.

Comment: Cant find that mode - A picture or a little more detail would definitely help

Comment: Found it. Thanks - Marked as answer

Answer (score 2):

In manual coding mode you can use **setTabOrder ( QWidget * first, QWidget * second )** for achieving customised tabbing.

Refer the link

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setTabOrder